# Obtain text from running application

Tags: python, c++, windows, user-interface, automation

Is it possible in a known way to obtain text within a running application GUI (presented to the screen, in menus or sidebars etc.), in a programmatic way ?

I have thought of somehow viewing the memory management of the program however this would prove difficult if a lot of dynamic allocation (the string) is going on (and I don't know how to).

I finally did use automated screenshots and text recognition from the images to achieve this, however this is clearly inefficient and I wanted to ask if there is a clever way that I am not aware of ?

Comment: like any window? even a windows window for example?

Comment: @andreihondrari Exactly. However I would of course pursue how to achieve the same in Linux if I succeed in Windows.

Comment: my personal opinion is that what you are asking is pretty SciFi. You would need to pinpoint the application's RAM spectrum and steal all the information from there, that if of course you know how to interpret the bits at those addresses.

Comment: @andreihondrari Probably, but I decided to ask because some person may make a good point. It comes to me as a task that is open to many view points and ideas.

Comment: Probably a stupid thought, but what about getting the data from a screen reader?

Comment: @Matthew0898 Very good idea in my opinion :) However it seems the application I am working on does not naturally support this. Besides, it actually comes down to the idea I already tried.